# Simple groups of order 7920

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

I would like to prove that every finite simple group of order 7920 is isomorphic to $M_{11}$. I would be appreciated if someone can give me some points.

Comment: Look up in Rotman's book, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't find it in Rotman's book

Comment: I would be appreciated if you let me know the Page of  Rotman's book that  I may find the answer>

Comment: If you look at the index, one chapter is devoted to Matheiu groups.

Comment: Rotman's book does not contain such a proof.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608916/on-the-simple-group-m-11 -- near duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838099/prove-that-a-group-is-isomorphic-to-the-mathieu-group-m-11 (which indicates the method of proof)

Comment: Its not very helpful to give other questions with no answers. And the method of proof indicated is not one I believe in, at least not without many further details.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I think I need to prove that $G$ is 4-transitive, but it seems too complicated.